# Access receiving email first name from email template

Tags: email-template

How to access to the Email Receiver First Name from the Email Template?

For example, I have to send an email to a specific user that have to approve a record and I want the email say:

'Hello {!emailOwner.FirstName}, a new record should be approved.'

I try {!Receiving_User.FirstName} and {!Target_User.FirstName} and both not working. I'm doing something wrong? In the email alert I use the 'User' Object and assign the user I want to receive the email into the recipient.

Answer (score 0):

{!Receiving_User.FirstName}, is working fine. 
You can also check your template by click [Send test and verify merge field] button is present on Email Template. You can preview the template by clicking this button:
[Select Particular Recipient from contact, lead or user and preview]